# Different views for different roles angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting three different roles from server like this-

```
["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MODERATOR", "ROLE_ADMIN"]
```

or

```
["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"]
```

If the user is not a moderator i don't want to access some pages to that user in my angular js application.What should i do.?

Comment: You can use this solution: https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission or write own based on http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Answer (score 1):

[angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission) is a third party module, Check this [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission) it may help you

Comment: We are using it on production +1

Answer (score 0):

The Simple solution is check the user role and hide/show the pages based on the user role..
Did all those things during login redirect.

Comment: i was storing these roles in some service, and then in my controller i am checking for role.On the basis of role i am using ng-if in my div tag, but on refereshing the page my service data is getting lost.

Comment: If you did that means you will achieve what you want.